# Need to dynamically rename XML elements then populate with values of subsequent sibling element values

Tags: xml, xslt

I've converted CSV to XML. Needing to dynamically rename XML elements and then populate with the values of subsequent sibling element values. After converting to XML, the first CSV column has defaulted to the XML element name `<col1>`. The second column `<col2>`, etc.

Request #1: Rename the default element name with the value of the element. For example, `<col1>Account_Name</col1>` needs to be converted to `<Account_Name>`.

Request #2: I need to populate the newly renamed elements (i.e. `<Account_Name>`) with the element values of each subsequent `<row>`. For example, the second `<row>` should be `<Account_Name>Acct ABC</Account_Name>`

The 1st `<row>` instance contains a `<Record>` element, which contains multiple date values. Starting with the 2nd `<row>` instance the values in `<col4>` and `<col5>` represent the "Amount" values. So the Amount correlates with the Date listed on the first `<row>`. (i.e. col4 represents Date 1/5/2020... Acct ABC has an Amount of 5 for the date 1/5/2020. Acct ABC has an Amount of 123 for the date 1/6/2020).

**Source XML**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
    <row>
        <col1>Account_Name</col1>
        <col2>Account_Code</col2>
        <col3>Level_Name</col3>
        <Record>
            <col4>1/5/2020</col4>
            <col5>1/6/2020</col5>
        </Record>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Acct ABC</col1>
        <col2>x123</col2>
        <col3>Level 1A</col3>
        <Record>
            <col4>5</col4>
            <col5>123</col5>
        </Record>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col1>Acct XYZ</col1>
        <col2>x456</col2>
        <col3>Level 1A</col3>
        <Record>
            <col4>456</col4>
            <col5>0</col5>
        </Record>
    </row>
</root>
```

**Desired XSLT Output:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
    <row>
        <Account_Name>Acct ABC</Account_Name>
        <Account_Code>x123</Account_Code>
        <Level_Name>Level 1A</Level_Name>
        <Record>
            <Date>1/5/2020</Date>
            <Amount>5</Amount>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <Date>1/6/2020</Date>
            <Amount>123</Amount>
        </Record>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Account_Name>Acct XYZ</Account_Name>
        <Account_Code>x456</Account_Code>
        <Level_Name>Level 1A</Level_Name>
        <Record>
            <Date>1/5/2020</Date>
            <Amount>456</Amount>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <Date>1/6/2020</Date>
            <Amount>0</Amount>
        </Record>
    </row>
</root>
```

Thank you in advance for your time. I would offer a sample XSLT solution but I honestly do not have anything worth sharing at this point.

Comment: Do you really need the "dynamically rename" part? You seem to know the names of the elements without needing to get them from the input XML - which would make this task much simpler.

Comment: That is a good point. I do suppose the "dynamically" portion of my question could be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="dates" select="row[1]/Record/*"/>
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="row[position() >1]">
             <row>
                <Account_Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="col1"/>
                </Account_Name>
                <Account_Code>
                    <xsl:value-of select="col2"/>
                </Account_Code>
                <Level_Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="col3"/>
                </Level_Name>
                <xsl:for-each select="Record/*">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                    <Record>
                        <Date>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$dates[$i]"/>
                        </Date>
                        <Amount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </Amount>
                    </Record>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This allows you to have any number of date columns.

Comment: Fantastic and elegant. This definitely does the trick! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following XSLT. It is using so called **Identity Transform** pattern.

It will give you a good head start.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="col1">
        <Account_Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Account_Name>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="col2">
        <Account_Code>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Account_Code>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="col3">
        <Level_Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Level_Name>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="col4">
        <Date>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Date>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="col5">
        <Amount>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Amount>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--ignore first <row>-->
    <xsl:template match="row[1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you this is a very helpful start, however the <Date> value is being populated with the Amount and each <row> should have 2 <Record> elements. Is there a way to avoid having to excplicity reference each col when doing xsl:template match? The full XML file has 734 columns (i.e. <col734>) so it isn't practical to have 734 xsl:templates